# Why is volley onErroResponse so useless?

Tags: android, android-volley

Why is Volleys errorResponse So useless?

It barely provides any information?
Bellow is a screen shot of the `VolleyError` object that it provides me.

[image]

It literally tell me nothing? I can explain cause and detailed Message till I go blue.

AM I just missing something or is there another place to find out why the request failed?

Because right now telling me ServerError doesn't help much.

[EDIT]

here is my code making the call:

```
public void Login(String mEmail, String mPassword) {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("grant_type", "password");
    params.put("username", "user@email.co.za");
    params.put("password", "123456");
    params.put("client_id","ManagementInterface");

     HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
     headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
     headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  

    GsonRequest<JsonObject> tokenRequest = new GsonRequest<JsonObject>(
            Request.Method.POST, "token", JsonObject.class, headers,
            params, new Response.Listener<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JsonObject response) {
                    String Token = "";
                    onOkResponseHandle(Token);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    onErrorResponseHandle(error);
                }
            }); 

    Network.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(tokenRequest);
}
```

I am trying to replicate this request using volley:
[Image***](http://bitoftech.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/TokenPostRequest.png)

GSONRequest Class:

```
 public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {
private final Gson gson = new Gson();
private final Class<T> clazz;
private final Map<String, String> headers;
private final Map<String, String> params;
private final Listener<T> listener;

/**
 * Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
 * 
 * @param url
 *            URL of the request to make
 * @param clazz
 *            Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
 * @param headers
 *            Map of request headers
 */
public GsonRequest(int method, String url, Class<T> clazz,
        Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, String> params,
        Listener<T> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, Network.getFullUrl(url), errorListener);
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.headers = headers;
    this.params = params;
    this.listener = listener;
}

/**
 * Recieves header
 * 
 * @param method
 * @param url
 * @param clazz
 * @param params
 * @param listener
 * @param errorListener
 */
public GsonRequest(int method, String url, Class<T> clazz,
        Map<String, String> params, Listener<T> listener,
        ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, Network.getFullUrl(url), errorListener);
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    this.params = params;
    this.listener = listener;
}

/**
 * No params or headers
 * 
 * @param method
 * @param url
 * @param clazz
 * @param listener
 * @param errorListener
 */
public GsonRequest(int method, String url, Class<T> clazz,
        Listener<T> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, Network.getFullUrl(url), errorListener);
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    this.params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    return params != null ? params : super.getParams();
}

    @Override
protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
    listener.onResponse(response);
}

@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String json = new String(response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What call(s) were you trying to make that caused this, and does this `ServerError` correspond with any specific issues on the remote server you're calling?

Comment: Well that's what Im trying to find out. its just a post to login with owin. But the error response doesnt help me debug the issue at all. ps will add the call.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for in an answer to this question. Specific to `ServerError`s, it does not surprise me volley doesn't return meaningful information - it's possible the server is simply returning a 500 error to volley.